# DB2 catalog tables for UDB and LUW

Tags: db2, odbc, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Is there a common set of catalog tables I can use between db2 udb (iseries) and db2 for linux, unix and windows?

currently the ruby sequel gem uses a schema called syscat which does not exist on db2 udb.

I have attempted to locate some commonalities between them in the ibm docs but I can't seem to figure out the best catalog tables to use. It seems like db2 udb has 3 different ones that can be used. is there a compatible set of catalog tables to use?

Answer (score 1):

With DB2 for IBM i there are 3 different catalog views available:

1. [IBM i catalog views](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcatalogtbls.htm?lang=en) are stored in schema QSYS2, for example QSYS2.SYSTABLES
2. [ODBC / JDBC catalog views](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcatalogodbc.htm?lang=en) are stored in schema SYSIBM, for example SYSIBM.SQLTABLES
3. [ANS / ISO catalog views](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcatalogans.htm?lang=en) have two schemas.  INFORMATION_SCHEMA is for low privilege users and SYSIBM is for high privilege users.  For example INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES or SYSIBM.TABLES

Comment: Do any of these catalogs match catalogs found in DB2 LUW?

Comment: I am an IBM i programmer, but DeveloperWorks shows base catalog tables in SYSIBM and user-level views in SYSCAT.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0411melnyk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of system tables on the iseries and plenty of views.  IDK if they match.
The tables and views are in QSYS2.

```
AUTHIDS             
AUTHORIZATIONS      
CATALOG_NAME        
CHARACTER_SETS      
CHARACTER_SETS_S    
CHECK_CONSTRAINTS   
CHECK_CSTS          
COLPRIV             
COLUMN_PRIVILEGES   
COLUMNS             
COLUMNS_S           
CONDENSEDINDEXADVICE
CONDIDXA            
DBMON_QUERIES       
FCN_INFO            
FCN_USAGE              
FUNCTION_INFO          
FUNCTION_USAGE         
GROUP_PROFILE_ENTRIE  >
GROUP_PTF_INFO         
GROUPLIST              
GRPPTFINFO             
INFORMATION_SCHEMA_C  >
JOURNAL_INFO           
JRNINFO                
JVM_INFO               
LIBLIST                
LIBRARY_LIST_INFO      
LOCATIONS              
PARAMETERS             
PARAMETERS_S     
PARM_S           
PGMSTMSTAT       
PKGSTMSTAT       
PROCEDURES       
PTF_INFO         
REF_CONSTRAINTS      
REF_CST1             
REF_CST2             
REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAI 
REPLY_LIST_INFO      
REPLYLIST            
ROUTINE_PRIVILEGES   
ROUTINES             
ROUTINES_S          
RTNPRIV             
SCHEMATA            
SCHEMATA_S          
SERVER_SBS_ROUTING  
SQL_FEATURES        
SQL_LANG_S          
SQL_LANGUAGES       
SQL_LANGUAGES_S     
SQL_SIZING          
SQLQMAUDIT          
SQLQMPROF           
SQLQMPROFILES       
SQLQMPROFILESAUDIT  
SRVRSBSRTG          
SYSCATALOGS     
SYSCAT1         
SYSCAT2         
SYSCHKCST       
SYSCHRSET1      
SYSCHRSET2      
SYSCOLAUTH      
SYSCOLUMNS      
SYSCOLUMNSTAT   
SYSCOLUMNS2     
SYSCOLUMN2      
SYSCST          
SYSCSTAT        
SYSCSTCOL       
SYSCSTDEP       
SYSDISKS        
SYSDISKSTAT     
SYSFEATURE      
SYSFIELDS       
SYSFUNCS        
SYSINDEXES      
SYSINDEXSTAT    
SYSIXADV        
SYSIXSTAT       
SYSJARCONT      
SYSJARCONTENTS  
SYSJAROBJ       
SYSJAROBJECTS   
SYSKEYCST       
SYSKEYS         
SYSLANGS    
SYSLIMITS   
SYSMQTSTAT           
SYSPACKAGE           
SYSPACKAGEAUTH       
SYSPACKAGESTAT       
SYSPACKAGESTMTSTAT   
SYSPARMS             
SYSPARTITIONDISK     
SYSPARTITIONINDEXDIS 
SYSPARTITIONINDEXES  
SYSPARTITIONINDEXSTA 
SYSPARTITIONMQTS     
SYSPARTITIONSTAT     
SYSPDISK             
SYSPGSTAT            
SYSPIDISK
```